# Jenkins CI + Ant + SSH Plugin

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

So the way I have this setup is:

1. Jenkins Polls for changes on repo
2. Jenkins Initiates Ant
3. Jenkins uses SSH plugin to run a script on a remove server (to run a git pull)

The problem is that if Ant fails, Jenkins still moves on to step 3 and processes the script.

How do I make Jenkins just stop everything after step 2?  Or is there a better way of doing my process?

Comment: Does the ANT build fail, or complete normally? Sounds like a stupid question, but it's possible to configure ANT to ignore task failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what I really needed was [Publish Over SSH](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) instead.  This enables you to include it in the Post Build Options.